# Describing a function with independent variables.

Tags: notation

The normal distribution is often written $f(x\,\rvert\,\mu,\sigma^2)$, with the independent variables on the right side of the vertical line. Is this notation common, or are alternatives? For instance, is there a way of splitting the function in two, one with the independent variables and one with the dependent ones? e.g. $\phi(\mu,\sigma^2)\circ \varphi(x)$, or is it simply too common to just assume that all variables not explicitly mentioned as a function parameter are independent variables?

Comment: The *variables* $x, \mu$ and $\sigma$ are the variables of the [normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#General_normal_distribution) function; thus, they are necessarily "free".

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA $x$ isn't a free variable.

Comment: Where is the "quantifier" in the formula ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA seems I'm confusing free/bound variables and dependent/independent variables. I'll rewrite/delete the question.

Comment: Having said that free/bound are defined in formal math log language, for a "semi-formal" math language the expression "acting" as quantifiers are the "big sum" $\Sigma$ or the intergral $\int$ symbols. Thus, in $\Sigma_i a_i$ the variable $i$ is "bound". In the expression $f(x)$, the variable $x$ can assume multiple values and for each value of $x$ we usually have a value for $f(x)$: in this sense, $x$ is *free*.